# Do any Python environments support edit-and-continue?

Tags: python, debugging

Is it possible in Python to make changes to code that you're currently debugging and continue without having to restart everything? (The way I can in C#, for example.)

Answer (score 12):

You have the full power of the interpreter at your fingertips with `pdb`, use

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

From there you can define and create new objects, redefine existing ones, modify and reload modules, etc.  Syntax is simalar to `gdb`.  If you're using ipython, `ipdb` may be a nicer choice, or you can automatically invoke the debugger with the ipython magic function `%debug`.

Comment: Good answer, but I would recommend using pdb through IPython, which makes it even more powerful (syntax highlighting, auto-debug on exceptions, etc.) (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You can give new values to names, but there might still be places that refer to the old value.  Check the session below at the python shell:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'Foo'
...
>>> bar = foo
>>>
>>> foo()
Foo
>>> bar()
Foo
>>>
>>> def foo(): print 'Bar'
...
>>> foo()
Bar
>>> bar()
Foo
>>>
>>> def call(): foo()
...
>>> call()
Bar
>>>
>>>
>>> def foo(): print 'Foo reloaded!'
...
>>>
>>> foo()
Foo reloaded!
>>> bar()
Foo
>>>
>>> call()
Foo reloaded!
>>>
```

The function `call` refers to the new `foo`, but `bar` was assigned the value of the old `foo` and that doesn't change when you reuse the name `foo`.

Were you asking for editor support?  [Python-mode in Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs) can run an "inferior python process" to which you can send blocks of code as you play with them.  Or you could do this directly in the Python shell, as shown above.